# How do I merge RasterBrick columns and rename after extract from NetCDF data ? [R language]

Tags: r, extract, netcdf, lubridate, r-raster

everyone I am just a beginner of R,so following code or question might misunderstand R function. Hopes you guys don't mind it.

1. I got hundreds ERA Interim Daily Precipitation data from ECMWF.
2. Each monthly NetCDF file contain twice per day precipitation and extract them by Longitude & Latitude.
3. Finally convert to CSV file,but itself store (12:00 ;00:00) two columns for 
   same days rainfall.

[Image of output CSV](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1mBrm8VkxvLx8ZOZjX6Y_Ny4A7GInfRsa)

Ideally ,I would like to obtain single day rainfall for whole year or month. But, don't know how to do it in R.

- **Q1:** Is there any library or function  support merge  columns names and keep 
  same dates?
- **Q2:** However, I am not sure lubridate library can accomplish or others will be 
  better.

-----Thanks for any answers---------

If somebody want to view NetCDF file and .csv file ,you can get from my google driver:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ogQp_-MlvmJCDmzm38dXHbUmWAM6hi1v?usp=sharing
P.S In Google Drive SumMonth.csv is extract result

R Code:

```
library(raster)
library(ncdf4)
f <- list.files("C:/Users/asus/Downloads/extract",
                pattern = "*.nc", full.names = TRUE)
ncloop <-lapply(f,nc_open)# Read whold folder nc.file

brick <-lapply(f,brick,varname = "tp")

brick2 <-stack(brick)# Combine all month

dim(brick2)#check dim right

##### input location file with Lon&Lat

pointCoordinates <- read.table("C:/Users/asus/Downloads/pointFile.csv",

header = TRUE, sep = ",",stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

coordinates(pointCoordinates) <- ~Long + Lat # Assign XY for extract

rasValue=extract(brick2, pointCoordinates)#extract

combinePointValue=cbind(pointCoordinates,rasValue)#construct database 

## Outout as csv
cc <- as.data.frame(combinePointValue)

write.csv(cc,file ="SumMonth.csv")
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please consider that users are often unwilling of downloading data from unknown sources. To facilitate users helping you, it would be better to share a minimal part of your data within the question. In this case, you could share the results of dput(head(cc[,1:10])) (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)